# Can I use a study visa in an expired passport?

Tags: visas, canada, study, passport-renewals

Can I travel to Canada with a valid study visa in my old expired passport? I now have a new passport, which does not have in a Canadian study visa.

Comment: The answer appears to be yes, but that assumes that you're traveling for study.  If you're traveling for another reason such as tourism, please advise by responding to this comment, and I will reopen the question.